# Adversary calculating signature of $m$ given a signature over $m'$ for textbook RSA

Tags: rsa, signature

Suppose $m$ is the message that the Eve attacker wants to sign with the RSA signature scheme with the public key $(n, e)$ and the private key $(n, d)$. Suppose the signer Eve is given oracle access to the signing algorithm for any other message such as $m'$, where $m'$ with $m' \neq m$. How can Eve calculate the signature of the message $m$?

Comment: What does 'opposite' mean?  And, is RSA padding used, or is this 'textbook RSA'?

Comment: Opposite mean's m != m' and used school book RSA

Comment: I think this is a homework question, and I think you are misunderstanding the term "opposite".

Comment: Are you saying that the signer is willing to sign any $m'$ that Eve specifies, as long as $m' \ne m$?

Comment: Yes that's right.

Comment: Oh, in that case, this homework problem is easy - what have you tried?

Comment: I've temporarily reopened the question so you can respond to poncho (use `@poncho`). Do **not** repost questions.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers your question because the the question is a bit unclear (I tried to edit it, but I don't know if it will be accepted).

Anyways take a look at this for example :

1. Eve sends for encryption to the oracle this : $km$ where both $k, n$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.
2. Gets back $r_1 = (kn)^d$.
3. Sends for encryption $k$ to the oracle.
4. Gets back $r_2 = k^d$.
5. Calculates $k=r_2^{-1}$.
6. Calculates $kr_1$

Comment: Typically, we don't give out straight answers to obvious homework questions.  I would note that this answer can be simplified if we just take $k = n-1$  (where $n$ is the modulus, not the value you select in step 1); steps 3-5 then become trivial...

Comment: Sorry, should I delete my answer?

Comment: @JAAAY : you can leave it; but next time it's a good idea to think about our [policy on that](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), also [this](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/90/555). And since your answer is there, I suggest to proofread: in 1 and 2 you want to change one $n$ to $m$. In 6, it's not crystal clear it's actually calculated $r_2^{-1}r_1$. The way to fix this is either to use poncho's suggestion, or to keep yours and introduce $r'_2=r_2^{-1}$, then compute $r'_2r_1$. Also an explanation that the calculations are made $\pmod n$ might help the OP.

Comment: Note: in general, $k$ of step 5 is not $k$ of steps 1 and 2. It can be though: just set $k=n-1$, in which case steps 3/4/5 are unnecessary.